# Angular 11 - Array mapping undefined

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I'm using api to get the response array, I'm trying to map the "id" under the "quiz_records" array but it returns undefined. I think that my code are correct.
This is my attempt.

array

```
"quizRemarks": [
        {
            "id": 160,
            "user_id": 1,
            "quiz_id": 18,
            "module_id": 29,
            "number_of_correct_answers": 2,
            "created_at": "2021-10-15T03:52:52.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-10-15T03:52:52.000000Z",
            "time_started": null,
            "time_finished": null,
            "remarks": 1,
            "quiz_records": [
                {
                    "id": 27,
                    "user_scores_id": 160,
                    "question_id": 2,
                    "user_answers": "DriverPH",
                    "remarks_correct_incorrect": "1",
                    "created_at": null,
                    "updated_at": null,
                    "question_text": "What is the name of this application?"
                },
                {
                    "id": 28,
                    "user_scores_id": 160,
                    "question_id": 2,
                    "user_answers": "Red",
                    "remarks_correct_incorrect": "1",
                    "created_at": null,
                    "updated_at": null,
                    "question_text": "What traffic light color tells you to stop before the intersection?"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

ts

```
this.quiz_records = res['quizRemarks'].map(res => res['quiz_records'].id);
console.log(this.quiz_records);
```

Comment: `quiz_records` in the JSON is an array. You cannot direct access `id` with `res['quiz_records'].id`.

Comment: What is the workaround?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 11 -Array map in ts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69624455/angular-11-array-map-in-ts)

Comment: Nope I can't seem to find the workaround there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're truing to get an id property from an array, what it inpossible.
You can use nested map + [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) array method.

```
const result = res['quizRemarks'].map(remarks => {
  return remarks['quiz_records'].map(record => record.id);
}).flat();
```

Answer (score 1):

`quizRemarks` is an array of objects containing an array of `quiz_records`. Try this to get a flat list of `ids` of `quiz_records`:

```
this.quiz_records = [];
this.quizRemarks.forEach(remark => {
  this.quiz_records.push(...remark.quiz_records.map(rec => rec.id));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code will work----

this.quiz_records = res['quizRemarks'].map(res => res['quiz_records'].map(r => r.id));